# Difference in hash map in java 7 and 8

Tags: java, hashmap

What is the difference in Hash Map of Java 7 and Java 8 when both works on constant complexity algorithm? As per my understanding hash map searches in constant time by generating a hash key for an object through hash function.

Comment: @MDaniyal answered correctly without using the phrase that describes the situation of two or more elements having the same hash: "hash collision." If you want to look deeper into hash collisions in general, I recommend starting here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Collision_resolution

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In Java 7 after calculating hash from hash function if more then one element has same hash than they are searched by linear search so it's complexity is (n). In Java 8 that search is performed by binary search so the complexity will become log(n). So, this concept is wrong that hash map searches an object in constant complexity because it is not the case at all times.

Comment: Actually there is an threshold, It is described in JEP180, when a single bucket/bin has more than TREEIFY_THRESHOLD=8 entries it will be converted into a tree. In Java 7 where collisions have been linearly searched there was a DOS protection: a random seed Xord with the hashes to make them less predictable. This function is removed in Java 8.

Comment: If we go deep in the implementation, it's exactly what you have explained @eckes

Answer (score 4):

You might find the latest issues of the Java Specialist [newsletter](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue235.html) very helpful. It goes into great depth discussing hashing in Java over the course of the years; for example pointing out that you better make sure your map keys implement Comparable (when using Java8).